# Lasso for non-stationary time series

Tags: regression, feature-selection, lasso, stationarity, spurious-correlation

Does it make sense to use Lasso to find an explanatory variable x to predict my variable y, assuming both y and x are non-stationary? (I'm using both variables as levels, not differences). If I find a high Rsquared, is this a sign that the regression is spurious?

Comment: What is your goal?